# On a product involving Ramanujan primes

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization, products

We denote the $k$th Ramanujan prime as $\mathcal{R}_k$, that is the sequence *A104272* from the OEIS as you can read from this [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime) Then I was inspired in Richard K. Guy, *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*, Springer, Volume I (1994), section B48 p. 102, to write the following conjecture*. In the Question below I am asking what can be elucidate about it.

By definition we know that there exist infinitely many Ramanujan primes.

**Conjecture.** For $n>1$ $$\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\mathcal{R}_k+1}{\mathcal{R}_k-1}\tag{1}$$
is never an integer.

> **Question.** My belief is that there exists an integer $n_0$ such that $(1)$ is never an integer $\forall n>n_0$. What work can be done about previous Conjecture or my belief? **Many thanks.**

---

*We can state similar conjectures that harmonize with previous one involving different prime constellations: if we write the $k$th term of the set of lesser of twin primes, I am saying *A001359* from the OEIS, denoted as $t_k$, instead of $\mathcal{R}_k$, **or well** if we write the $k$th Sophie Germain prime, *A005384*, denoted as $\mathcal{G}_k$, instead of $\mathcal{R}_k$.

Comment: Everyone, I hope that some user wants to provide an answer/contribution for this post. I am asking what work can be done about the veracity of the **Conjecture** or about the solution of the **Question.** I am waiting calculations, reasonings or heuristics. Many thanks.

Comment: I personally think this seems very interesting and am sorry few have seen it fit to answer. May I ask, what reasoning did *you* have behind this conjecture? What have you seen to suggest it might be true?

Comment: If I have some time, I might create a computer check of this for some large numbers.

Comment: I'm an amateur and I did the similar conjecture showed in Guy's book, now for Ramanujan primes. My feeling is (in the past I was mathematician) that maybe it can be interesting (because Ramanujan primes have a great mathematical content). But I have no computational evidence. Many thanks for your attention and help @IskyMathews . And feel free to study in your home other cases for different prime constellations (the lesser of twin primes or Germain primes).

Comment: Just saying, when I sat down and actually thought about it for a second, I realised that if we take the case of $n=1$, your product is just $\frac{2+1}{2-1} = 3$, so I presume you wish to investigate your "Question" rather than the initial conjecture?

Comment: I am saying $n>1$ because I know that for $n=1$ we get the integer $3$. And I wrote the first few cases to convince myself that there isn't an obvious counterexample @IskyMathews

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry, didn't read correctly. Right - I've written a program which can calculate Ramanujan primes (this is surprisingly complex) and optimised it with some bounds from Sondlow et al. I have also written something to calculate your product. Let's have a gander...

Comment: No please, don't say *I'm sorry*. Many thanks for your attention and when you want do your contribution @IskyMathews

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78076/discussion-between-isky-mathews-and-user243301).

Comment: The product itself is likely to be diverge very slowly.

Comment: @didgogns, I have given this some thought, and I think I can show you are correct. We know that the sum of the Ramanujan primes' reciprocals diverges and that sum up to $R_k$ looks like $\frac{R_1+R_2+...+R_k}{R_1R_2...R_k}$. The product-above-up-to-$R_k$'s numerator clearly contains $R_1+R_2+R_3...$ in its terms and the denominator $(R_1-1)(R_2-1)(R_3-1)...<R_1R_2R_3...$ trivially. So for each $k$, the product's partial-evaluation is larger than that of the sum, so the product diverges.

Comment: @didgogns good remark, many thanks also for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

I can now say with some certainty that this conjecture holds for the first 500 Ramanujan primes (though my computer has checked to some number above that $\leq 600$), which is pretty large (8831), though I don't have the fastest programs in the world.

Also, see my comment in reply to @didgogns, where I give a proof/proof-sketch to show that this product does indeed diverge.

I shall now consider some heuristics...

**EDIT I**: However unrelated to the question, it occurs to me that what I proved in the comment section in fact shows that $$\prod^{n}_{k=1}\frac{P_n+m}{P_n-m}$$ diverges for any $m\in\mathbb{R}^+$, as long as the sum of the reciprocals of the sequence $P_n$ diverge (i.e. $P_n$ could be the primes, the Ramanujan primes etc.).

**EDIT II**: My program has now verified the conjecture for the first 700 Ramanujan primes, though with potentially less certainty than before, since floating-point errors become a bit more important at this level...

**EDIT II**: I realise that I made a mistake in my proof in the comment section, saying that the numerator of the sum of the reciprocals of $R_i$ would looke like $R_1+R_2+R_3...$, whereas it would instead look like the sum of all $k$-products (products of $k$ of the primes). **This doesn't change the conclusion of the proof**, however, as it is still true that $(R_1+1)(R_2+1)(R_3+1)...$ contains in its expansion all of these terms and many more (in fact, it contains the sum of all $i$-products, for all $1\leq i \leq k$).

**EDIT III**: This is probably highly unnecessary at this point, but my program has now verified this conjecture (with much less certainty) to the first 800 Ramanujan primes.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution, feel free to edit adding those claims that you think useful for my and the other users interested in this post.